# UWP, App.Xaml: Override default brushes

Tags: xaml, uwp

If I need to override a color in a brush, I would set it into App.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources> 

     ...

       <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush" Color="#A7A9AC" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush" Color="Black" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>

         ...
</Application.Resources>
```

The editor underlines `<ResourceDictionary>` saying: "Each dictionary entry must have an associated key".

How can solve this?

Comment: What is holding the ResourceDictionary (what's the parent object/XAML)?

Comment: <Application.Resources> ... </Application.Resources>

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue when I included only the xaml code in app.xaml. Can you reproduce the issue in a blank UWP project with these xaml code only? Maybe you have more things there? It will be helpful if you can provide the repro steps with a new blank project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem, thanks to @Alan Yao - MSFT.
`Maybe you have more things there?`, I had something else, written into the `ResourceDictionary`. By making `ResourceDictionary` parent of everything inside `Application.Resources`, I solved the problem.

Comment: Yeeesss... I was struggling with this issue for to long. Big thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

The ResourceDictionary has to be placed inside application resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush" Color="#A7A9AC" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush" Color="Black" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: @misiMe Ok, I had answered before you have added comment to your question. So no reason for point down.